# Java dates difference in milliseconds

Tags: java, date, time

I've written the following code, but I always just get...

4838399999
Seconds is : 59
Minutes is : 59
Hours is : 23
Days is : 7

```
Calendar xmas = Calendar.getInstance();
final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

xmas.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
xmas.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
xmas.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);

long milliseconds1 = now.getTimeInMillis();
long milliseconds2 = xmas.getTimeInMillis();
long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
System.out.println(diff);
diff = diff / 1000;

final long diffSeconds = diff % 60;
System.out.println("Seconds is : " + diffSeconds);
diff = diff / 60;

final long diffMinutes = diff % 60;
System.out.println("Minutes is : " + diffMinutes);
diff = diff / 60;

final long diffHours = diff % 60;
System.out.println("Hours is : " + diffHours);
diff = diff / 24;

final long diffDays = diff % 24;
System.out.println("Days is : " + diffDays);
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this logic to find the days, hours, minutes and seconds till xmas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do:

```
diff = diff / 1000;
```

you're permanently losing the remainder.  It should be something like:

```
long seconds = diff / 1000; // seconds is milliseconds / 1000
long milliseconds = diff % 1000; // remainder is milliseconds that are not composing seconds.
long minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
```

The same pattern of the last four continues.

Comment: Well, he doesn't *need* the remainder any more, so that's really not a problem.

Comment: @ruakh, you're right.  I read it too quickly and thought `milliseconds` was used somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are wrong:

```
final long diffHours = diff % 60

final long diffDays = diff % 24;
```

Also, you're not setting the hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds on `xmas`, so it gets the hours, minutes, and seconds from the current time. For example, if you run the program at 4:30:20 AM, then it will give you the time until 4:30:20 AM on Christmas. You probably want the time until 00:00:00 on Christmas.